# WCF - Can't Generate Metadata/Implement MEX for NetMsmq Binding under IIS WAS?

Tags: wcf

I have been successfull in implementing NetTcp bindings and metadata under WAS but I am having a problem with the netMsmqBinding under WAS/IIS. In a nutshell, I can implement MEX for a Self Hosted NetMsmq binding application but not WAS/IIS. It seems like WAS is rejecting any of the addresses that I use where I can use any address in the self hosted app. In other words I can do this in self hosted:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Microsoft.Samples.MSMQTransactedSample.OrderProcessorService" behaviorConfiguration="OrderProcessorServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Define NetMsmqEndpoint -->
        <endpoint address="net.msmq://localhost/private/ServiceModelSamplesTransacted" binding="netMsmqBinding" bindingConfiguration="TransactedBinding" contract="Microsoft.Samples.MSMQTransactedSample.IOrderProcessor" />
        <!-- the mex endpoint is exposed at http://localhost:8000/ServiceModelSamples/service/mex -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="OrderProcessorServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <netMsmqBinding>
        <binding name="TransactedBinding">
          <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
      </netMsmqBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Hoever, when I try something similar in WAS, it says no endpoint lisening at address 8000. It won't host the metdata. Can someone help me get metadata or implement MEX for NetMsmq in WAS:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <netMsmqBinding>
        <binding name="MsmqBindingNonTransactionalNoSecurity" exactlyOnce="false">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </netMsmqBinding>
    </bindings>
  <services>  
      <service name="Portal.LoadSim.Services.MsmqService" behaviorConfiguration="PortalServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/PortalLoadSimServices10/MsmqService"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <!-- Define NetMsmqEndpoint -->
        <endpoint address="net.msmq://localhost/private/PortalLoadSimServices10/MsmqService.svc" binding="netMsmqBinding" bindingConfiguration="MsmqBindingNonTransactionalNoSecurity" contract="Portal.LoadSim.Shared.IMsmqService" />
        <!-- the mex endpoint is exposed at http://localhost:8000/PortalLoadSimServices10/MsmqService/mex -->
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

      </service>

    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="PortalServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add URL access control for your services. This command should work for you:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://localhost:8000/PortalLoadSimServices10/MsmqService user="NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" listen=yes
```

To delete the entry

```
delete urlacl url=http://localhost:8000/PortalLoadSimServices10/MsmqService
```

HTH

**UPDATE:** This is not the anwer to your problem. This is what you would do if you wanted to run the services as a self-hosted application and run it under non-standard account. Sorry I was getting it mixed up. I tried using your configuration on a sample application at home and found I had to do two things to get it to work - one, I have to rename the queue to the path and name of the svc file (e.g. PortalLoadSimServices10/MsmqService.svc) and rather than using the base address just browse to the svc file in your IIS host application. You might also need to modify the queue permissions so iis can access it correctly. Let me know if this solves your issue.

Comment: Same error - There was an error downloading 'http://localhost:8000/PortalLoadSimServices10/MsmqService/mex/'.Unable to connect to the remote server No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8000. There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8000/PortalLoadSimServices10/MsmqService/mex/ that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Comment: I tried Add Service Reference to http://localhost:8000/PortalLoadSimServices10/MsmqService/mex

Comment: Delete urlacl entry and try adding the full address to your metadata, including the mex (which wasn't in the command I put into the post).